# Issues with presenting image from parsed JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Im having a problem with some code and see if you guys can help me out with it. 
Im fairly new to objective C and programming for the iPhone in general so any feedback would be amazing.

Im trying to parse urls of images of flickr for from JSON file. I successfully retrieved the data and created strings of the urls needed to send to UIImageView. However I seem to have a problem with it showing the image on the screen. The only thing that shows on screen is my UIImageView box that is blue color but no images from flickr. I tried to pinpoint the problem where I think it has something to do with my photoURLS mutable array not being initalized correctly or something because when I print out an element from the array it does print it but then right after prints out its null.

If you guys could take a look to help me figure out whats wrong or even suggest a better alternative to what i want to do that would be great.

Below is the only thing in my ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *photoURLS;

@end
```

Below is the code I have in my ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



-(id)init {


    self = [super init];

    if(self) {




        [self loadFlickrPhotos];

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)loadFlickrPhotos {

NSString* urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&sort=random&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=rocket&tag_mode=all&api_key=0e2b6aaf8a6901c264acb91f151a3350&nojsoncallback=1"];
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlstring];

    self.photoURLS = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

  NSArray* photos = [[parsedObject valueForKey:@"photos"]objectForKey:@"photo"];

    for(NSDictionary* photo in photos) {

        NSString* photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_m.jpg", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"],[photo objectForKey:@"server"],[photo objectForKey:@"id"],[photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];


        [self.photoURLS addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]];




          }
         NSLog(@"Photo #: %i", self.photoURLS.count);
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{




    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {



    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self.photoURLS objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"Photo from url is: %@",[self.photoURLS objectAtIndex:35]);
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];

    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

   [super viewDidAppear:YES];


}
@end
```

In the console when i try to check if it is working it looks like this:

```
2014-03-06 13:03:09.395 FlickrRocket[5011:11303] Photo #: 100
2014-03-06 13:03:09.705 FlickrRocket[5011:11303] Photo from url is: http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3678/12943650293_faf143aca1_m.jpg
2014-03-06 13:03:09.707 FlickrRocket[5011:11303] Photo from url is: (null)
```

Comment: Did you make sure imageData is not nil after calling dataWithContentsOfURL?

Comment: Yes when i attempted to print imageData instead of the url it gave me the same thing "all the correct data, but then right after said it was (null)". So not sure why the console is printing that out twice since i only created one NSLog statement for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't load the load the photos in init.
Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadFlickrPhotos];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self.photoURLS objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"Photo from url is: %@",[self.photoURLS objectAtIndex:35]);
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];

    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)loadFlickrPhotos
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much that helped :) Could you possibly explain to me what the problem was? I'm still not used to how initializing works and what gets called first.

Comment: Init gets called right after allocating. In ViewControllers you normally initialize your member variables, or don't even overload it.
viewDidLoad is a good place to kick-off loading operations.
viewDidAppear gets called every time, when the view appears.
In this case it would also be practical to load the image directly in viewDidLoad, as it doesn't need to be reloaded if the view appears again. (But thats highly dependent on the use case).